# Java- gzip member trailer

Tags: java, compression, format, gzip

This is part of a larger assignment that I've mostly got done except for this one part, which is a bit embarrassing because it sounds really simply on paper.

So basically, I've got a large amount of compressed data. I've been keeping track of the length using a CRC32

```
CRC32 checksum = new CRC32();
...
//read input into buffer
checksum.update(buff, 0, bytesRead);
```

So it updates everytime more info is read in. I've also kept track of the uncompress length using

```
uncompressedLength += manage.read(buff);
```

So it is an int value that has the number of bytes of the original file. This is a little Endian machine.

From what I can tell, what I need is four byte CRC, which I used

```
public byte[] longToBytes(long x) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    buffer.putLong(x);
    return buffer.array();
}

byte[] c = longToBytes(checksum.getValue());
```

BUT this is 8 bytes. CRC32.getValue returns a long. Can I convert it to an int in this case without losing information I need?

And then the ISIZE is supposed to be...the four byte compressed length modulo 2^32. I've got the variable uncompresedLength which is an int. I think I just have to convert it to bytes and that's all?

I've been hexdumping the result from gzip and the result from my program and my header and data are right, I'm just missing my trailer.

As for why I'm doing this manually, it's because of an assignment. Trust me, I'd love to just use GZIPOoutputStream if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRC32 has 32 bits... the class returns `long` because of the super interface.

uncompressed length should be `long`, since nowadays files larger than 2G isn't uncommon.

so in both cases, you need to convert the lowest 32 bits of a long to 4 bytes.

```
static byte[] lower4bytes(long v)
{
    return new byte[] {
            (byte)(v    ),
            (byte)(v>> 8),
            (byte)(v>>16),
            (byte)(v>>24)
    };
}
```

Comment: If it's just the lower 32 bits, would just casting (int)checksum.getValue() be the same...or does that actually cut off something I need. Because if that works, I can convert the int to bytes with a byte buffer...I think

Comment: in general, narrowing long to int may be dangerous. see my update for get the lower 4 bytes of a long.

Answer (score 0):

To write an integer in little-endian form, simply write the low byte of the integer (i.e. modulo 256 or anded with 0xff), then shift it down eight bits or divide by 256, then write the resulting low byte, and repeat that two more times.  You'll write four bytes.  Since you only write four, you will automatically be writing the length modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.